# Filtros de excel con vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb6, vbscript

Estoy modificando un archivo de [excel](/questions/tagged/excel), y debo filtrar varios valores en una columna.

Ejemplo: en la columna *C*, filtrar `valor1`, `valor2`, *...*, `valor_n`.

Esto es lo que estuve probando, pero sin resultados, lo estoy trabajando en **visual basic.net**

```
oSheet.Range("c1").Select()
Arrfilter1(0) = "AJ001"
oSheet.Range("c1").AutoFilter(Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("AJ001", "AJ003", "AJ004", "AJ007", "AJ008", "HD002", "HD005", "SJ002", "SJ005", "SJ015", "SJ017", "31201"), VisibleDropDown:=True, Operator:=Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr)
```